# Why doesn't django automatically update the foreign key? (obj.relative.id != obj.relative_id)

Tags: django, django-models

I have code like this (Django 1.4.3):

```
class Peon(models.Model)
  # ...
  order = models.ForeignKey(Order, db_column='idOrder')
  # ... 

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.order_id is None:
      self.order = Order()

    #edit self.order's fields appropriately
    self.order.generate(...)

    self.order.save()

    super(Peon, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

super().save() complains that the order doesn't exist.

In other words, self.order_id remains None even when self.order.pk is set, and this prevents me from saving self.

My fix was to do this before calling super().save():

```
self.order_id = self.order.pk
```

My question is, why is this necessary? It feels like self.order.save() should automatically update the foreign key, but there must be a good reason why it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

When you generate an order by `self.order = Order()`, the id is not set as it is when you call the order’s `save` method. So your `order_id` field for your `Peon` object is set to None.

If all of your order’s field are optional you can do something like `self.order = Order.objects.create()` and then the id will be set correctly.

Otherwise you will need to do something like

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  if self.order_id is None:
    order = Order()
    #edit self.order's fields appropriately
    order.generate(...)
    self.order = order

  else:
    #edit self.order's fields appropriately
    self.order.generate(...)

  self.order.save()

  super(Peon, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If `order.generate` doesn't need the backward relation of course.

Comment: You're right, but that's actually what I have in my code already (it'd generate an infinite loop as-written) -- I've now updated the question.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I see the difference between your code and mine. It's clear that doing self.order=Order() sets self.order_id to None, but self.order.save() doesn't set self.order_id --- it just sets self.order.id. That's kind of weird, right? The only difference between your block of code and mine is that yours creates a variable 'order' instead and then assigns it to self.order, whereas mine works directly on self.order.

Comment: Maybe you meant to save order before assigning it to self.order? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Yes if I correctly understand your comment you get the point. Hence you need to save the order before setting `this.order`. This because Django handles relationship by primary keys and not objects themselves, so if you change the primary key the relationship is broken.